# show two table side by side on top and float second table up in html

Tags: html, css

I have two tables and I want them to appear side by side thus I used prop in CSS `(display: inline-block;)`;

But the problem is the second table is floated at the bottom where the first table is ending. i.e both 1st and 2nd table bottom is coming at same line,
whereas I want the 1st line of both tables to appear on the same line.

```
(display: inline-block;)
```

Comment: Please provide your code or atleast jsfiddle to get help.

Comment: can you fiddle here

Comment: @ChandraShekhar It is required that code be placed on this site, not a fiddle. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but make sure the tables aren't too big to be floated together. Here is an example:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50vw;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

table:nth-of-type(1) tr {
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10vw;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

table:nth-of-type(2) tr {
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10vw;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create like this to side by side table.

Following an example

jsfiddle example

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr3v5oqL/)**

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td>HELLO</td>
      <td>HELLO</td>
      <td>HELLO</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td>HELLO</td>
      <td>HELLO</td>
      <td>HELLO</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```